# Translate Hindi language to English using Python

Tags: python, google-translate, google-api-python-client, microsoft-translator

I'm doing a project on recognizing language(English, Hindi, Marathi, etc..) depends on origin language code and translate it into another language depends on input targeted language code.

Everything is done in Python language.

Google API to recognize language and interpret in text format then using Microsoft API translate it into another language.

But I'm facing an error, here it is

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
  File "pitranslate.py", line 60, in < module >
  translation_result = requests.get(translation_url + urllib.urlencode(translation_args), headers = headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1332, in urlencode
v = quote_plus(str(v))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can 't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My input: `क्या कर रहे हो`

Here is the complete code:

```
import json
import requests
import urllib
import subprocess
import argparse
import speech_recognition as sr
from subprocess import call

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This is a demo script by DaveConroy.com.')
parser.add_argument('-o','--origin_language', help='Origin Language',required=True)
parser.add_argument('-d','--destination_language', help='Destination Language', required=True)
#parser.add_argument('-t','--text_to_translate', help='Text to Translate', required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

## show values ##
print ("Origin: %s" % args.origin_language )
print ("Destination: %s" % args.destination_language )
#print ("Text: %s" % args.text_to_translate )

# obtain audio from the microphone
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")

    audio = r.listen(source)
args.text_to_translate = r.recognize_google(audio, language=args.origin_language) 
text = args.text_to_translate
#text=r.recognize_google(audio)
print text
origin_language=args.origin_language
destination_language=args.destination_language


def speakOriginText(phrase):
    googleSpeechURL = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl="+ origin_language +"&q=" + phrase
    subprocess.call(["mplayer",googleSpeechURL], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

def speakDestinationText(phrase):
    googleSpeechURL = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=" + destination_language +"&q=" + phrase
    print googleSpeechURL
    subprocess.call(["mplayer",googleSpeechURL], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

args = {
        'client_id': 'create and enter your client id',
        'client_secret': 'create id and enter here',#your azure secret here
        'scope': 'http://api.microsofttranslator.com',
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
    }

oauth_url = 'https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13'
oauth_junk = json.loads(requests.post(oauth_url,data=urllib.urlencode(args)).content)
translation_args = {
        'text': text,
        'to': destination_language,
        'from': origin_language
        }

headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer '+oauth_junk['access_token']}
translation_url = 'http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate?'
translation_result = requests.get(translation_url+urllib.urlencode(translation_args),headers=headers)
translation=translation_result.text[2:-1]

speakOriginText('Translating ' + translation_args["text"])
speakDestinationText(translation)
```

How to overcome this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Comment: Did you get an answer for this?

Answer (score 2):

For this error you have to decode your text in Utf-8 like example
You have text in other language
My_input=क्या कर रहे हो
now for use this text to convert or translate you have to use decode

```
My_input=क्या कर रहे हो
My_input.decode("utf-8")
```

like this you can decode and encode strings